# Why at sunset the sky looks like a rainbow?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science, sun

Why at sunset the sky looks like a rainbow?The higher part looks blue then as we look lower and lower we see white, yellow, orange and finaly red...as in the picture. Why the red light is so much scattered? Is this Rayleigh scattering? Are these zones telling that as the atmosphere goes thicker the intensity of scattered long wavelengths is dominant? Can this be explained by suposing that the range of scattered light is longer for longer wavelengths?In simple words i.e. only 50% of scattered blue while let say 80% of red ligth reach the observer eyes...Or we just see all the colors but the blue due to clouds in the sky? Also, why in the 'red zone' there is a tick yellow ring around the Sun?
[image]

Comment: The angle of incidence affects the shifting of the frequency of incident light.  At zero angle of incidence, i.e., scattering along the line of sight, the light tends to be red-shifted.  At an orthogonal angle of incidence, the light tends to be blue-shifted.  In between you can get a wide range of colors.  This is further complicated by pollution, which can scatter/refract light adding to the range of observed colors.